# What's our policy on questions asked merely for hats?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, policy

Let's say I just posted this to get a hat. What is our policy on such questions, either on Meta or on the main site?

Comment: As long as its a good question, its fine

Comment: (Did you just post this to get a hat??)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Nope, I got the hat earlier by voting. Now I'm testing for secret ones with this :P

Comment: Apparently "This is fine"

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/is-it-ok-to-ask-a-meta-question-just-to-get-a-hat) :-P

Comment: The tag [tag:winterbash] does not exist.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος It exists on meta (`[meta-tag:winterbash]` -> [meta-tag:winterbash]), just not on main.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 No, I meant that only this question uses it. Sorry, I meant [meta-tag:winterbash].

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος The tag exists on [meta.se], so I assumed that it would be an acceptable tag here.

Comment: @Mithrandir Why not? I didn't say you shouldn't use it, I just thought that you might have put it in by accident.

Comment: Do we really have a hat for asking puzzles? *sings* "Oompa loompa doompety doo I've got another puzzle for you..."

Comment: @ABcDexter if you ask it on the hour now...

Comment: @Mithrandir Yes, sure, maybe on new year day. I am kinda busy doing nothing :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Our policy is that you are a terrible person. (not really, but it's a catchy hook)

Hat-seeking behavior, while fine in absentia, is no excuse for cluttering the site with low-quality posts or inconsequential edits. Earn your hats fairly, through the usual channels.

Comment: There's very little we can actually do, except "c'mon, don't do that, please."

Comment: "inconsequential edits"... I've seen a ton of these popping up lately in the active question section.